# Aquarium Salt and Pink Salt

Tags: aquarium, fish

Is Himalayan pink salt okay to use in fish tanks? I have read that aquarium salt is good for conditioning water but I was curious if pink salt would do the trick as well?

Comment: It would probably be ok by why waste the money using expensive salt on an aquarium? If you're going to condition water with salt, just get some cheap, non-iodized table salt. No reason whatsoever to use himalayan pink salt for this. Additionally, since actual himalayan salt is unrefined, you are likely putting unknown metals and elements in the tank which is never a good idea.

Comment: For a salt water tank you need sea salt; For the small amount used in fresh water tank, it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Himalayan salt is typically used for cooking.. I would recommend you go to your local pet store and buy some aquarium specific salt. Like this [one](https://www.petco.com/shop/en/petcostore/product/api-aquarium-salt). 3 bucks and you know you're getting exactly what you need!

Please dont't use the cooking salt/seasoning salt, use fish salt!